# Default dark text color in dark mode on the action bar

Tags: android, android-theme, android-dark-theme

In light mode I have no problems because everything is correct but in dark mode without making any changes the text remains dark. Is it an Android bug?
I have tried various methods but my problem is that I have to disable some menu options and then I lose the color in disabled mode, it always seems enabled.
Is it just my problem? In this way the text is illegible
I use this theme: Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might be reading the colors for both dark and light mode from the same color resource. You need to create another color resource file for dark values and then it should automagically work.

And I am not sure if `DarkActionBar` is the right one to put there on the theme.

You should have something like this:

```
res -> values -> colors.xml
res -> values-night -> colors.xml
```

Comment: I added the color file for the dark theme because it didn't exist, but now how should I proceed? It doesn't seem to me to change the result on the menu. Also because the colors are wrong only in that part of the app, otherwise it is all correct.

Comment: How are you setting the dark mode? from phone settings?

Comment: Yes, from the settings. The problem is right when the app is started but only if I start the project with Navigation Drawer View

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't want the color to when user switch in dark/light mode then remove the night-theme file from res>values

and add change this in remained theme file

```
    <style name="app_name" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

into

```
<style name="app_name" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

if your parent is different than than change it into oneof light mode of it

Comment: I want the theme to change between dark and light like it is now. The problem is that that part is illegible, the text should be light and not dark.

Comment: @DavideTorchia i think you are using android menu so try useing this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66356603/21396301 in this worked for me in starting developing days. But i recommend to use popupmenu which is very helpful and easy if you need to change anything.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work, the problem is right when the app is started but only if I start the project with Navigation Drawer View